# Can't start systemd user instance

Tags: centos, rhel, systemd, services

I'm using CentOS 7, and am trying to create a systemd service for my local user. However, before I can do that, I need my systemd user instance, which I cannot find or create to begin with.

Running `systemctl --user` gives me

`Failed to issue method call: Process /bin/false exited with status 1`

Running `systemctl status user@1000.service` (where 1000 is the id given to me from the `id` command) gives me

```
user@1000.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

How do I find/create my systemd user instance?

Comment: The second command looks correct to me. Works under OpenSUSE 13.2. It finds the unit file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/user@.service.` and that file belongs to package `systemd-210-25.5.4.x86_64` I have no CentOS 7 handy now...

Answer (score 3):

Try to run `systemctl status user@root.service`, replace the user root for your user, to start the service just run `systemctl start user@root.service` (if the service is inactivated).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately replacing 1000 with root gives the same "not found" response.

Comment: go to the root directory and try to run "find -name user@.service" to locate where the service is.

Comment: that turns up nothing but `find: ‘./run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied`. My user service files seem to be nowhere.

Comment: are you as root user?

Comment: yeah, i tried with sudo, same results

Comment: in my case its located on "./lib/systemd/system/user@.service", but for run this service you need to run "systemd-user-sessions.service" after, its seems you don't have the user service... Are you already read this article "https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User"?

Comment: Yeah I can't find any user-related service file in that directory. I read that article earlier, and it didn't say how to create a user instance either. I don't have `/etc/pam.d/system-login`, or have any idea where `pam_systemd.so` is.

Comment: @xiankai this answer worked for me. I replace "root" user "foouser". You replaced it in 2014 with "1000". I think you need to use the username, not the user-id.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to create a user-owned systemd service, I ended up putting

```
...

[Service]
...
User=1000
```

the user directive in the systemd file, which seems to run the service as my user and thus has the same intended result as a user-owned systemd service.

My own system remains a mystery to me, however.